# How should I organize calculating functions inside a React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently building a React web app where a user inputs data across many tabs, and it does math to combine all the inputs, showing different steps along the way. Currently, the functional component takes objects from different tabs as props, then feeds those into plain javascript functions I have in a seperate file, which returns the appropriate number. The values build on each other, so given a bunch of values, function a would add specific ones to return value x. Then function b would call function a, and change it, returning y. Function a and b are called separately within the functional component, so I can't combine them.

The issue I'm coming across is that it feels too messy and like there's a better way to do it. If function a needs params j, k, and l, then function b would need j, k, l, and whatever it's adding because it calls function a. It doesn't seem like I need a React component for it, as there are too many lines to do it inside the component or function without having a massive, difficult to read file. A solution I thought of was making the helper functions methods in a class, where I only need to call a constructor with the objects that contain all the fields, but I'm unsure of how to do it, or if would actually solve anything.

Here's some example code to give an idea, but the actual thing has much more math, many more active input fields, and more helper functions.

### Functional Component

```
function Example({tab1, tab2}) {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("")
  const [inputValue2, setInputValue2] = useState("")
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setInputValue(e.target.value);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <input value={inputValue} onChange={handleChange} />
      <input value={calcValue1(inputValue, tab1)} />
      <input value={calcValue2(inputValue, tab1, tab2)} />
      <span>
        {/* Percent value of value2 */}
        <input value={inputValue2} onChange={handleChange} />
        <input value={calcValue2(inputValue, tab1, tab2) * parseFloat(inputValue2) / 100 />
      </span>
    </div>
  )
}
```

### Helper functions

```
const calcValue1 = (inputValue, tab1) => {
  let total = 0;
  total += parseFloat(inputValue) * tab1.first;
  total += tab1.second;
  return total;
}
const calcValue2 = (inputValue, tab1, tab2) => {
  let total = tab2.first;
  total -= calcValue1(inputValue, tab1);
  total += tab2.second / tab2.third;
  return total;
}
```

I might just be getting in my own head and this is fine, but something feels off and inefficient about this method. I appreciate any response.

**Edit:** Another thing I'm concerned about is performance, since each of the functions will run each time a new value is input to one of the fields, and lodash memoize only works with the first parameter.

Comment: those helper functions look totally fine to me

Comment: You might not need to use useMemo at all. Its only advisable if your functions really take long to finish. For example, your function maps through thousands of json data. See link below for more context
https://kentcdodds.com/blog/usememo-and-usecallback

Comment: @fardown [Here's an example of what one of the higher level functions look like in the code](https://ibb.co/phrwjJR), do you think it would need memo? It's mostly arithmetic, so probably not, huh.

Comment: On the performace tab of chrome dev tools, select 6x slow down (to emulate slow mobile phones), then trigger the higher level functions. If re-rerendering the component is taking too long then you should use usememo.